# query geoflutterfire as firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query firebase with the following requirements:
If I have a location, I want to receive the data in a certain radius through the GeoFlutterfire plugin.
If I don't have a location, I want to receive data with a limit.
I don't know if I do it correctly, but I am having problems preparing the stream.
With firestore's .`snapshot()` method, I get a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`, but with Geoflutterfire's `collection(...).Within(...)` method, I get a `Stream <List <DocumentSnapshot>>`. This gives me trouble when trying to display the data.
If anyone can clear my mind, I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

```
Consumer<LocationProvider>(
  builder: (_, location, __) {
    if (location.loading) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    final ref =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("publicaciones");
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream;
    final pos = location.direccion?.geoPoint;
    if (pos != null) {
      final geo = Geoflutterfire();
      stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(
            center: geo.point(
              latitude: pos.latitude,
              longitude: pos.longitude,
            ),
            field: "direccion.geoHash",
            radius: radio,
          );
    }
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream ?? ref.snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(
              "Error recibiendo publicaciones cercanas: ${snapshot.error}");
          return Text("Error recibiendo publicaciones.");
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final List<Publicacion> publicaciones = snapshot.data
              .map((p) => Publicacion.fromSnapshot(p))
              .toList();
          if (publicaciones.length == 0) {
            return Text("No hay publicaciones cercanas.");
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: publicaciones.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Text(publicaciones[index].titulo);
            },
          );
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  },
)
```

PS: I know that `stream: stream ?? ref.snapshots()` is not the best way to program, but my head is a bit clouded today, sorry.
I don't know if the title of the post describes my problem, so if you can think of a better one, I'll change it.

SOLUTION:
Thanks to William Cardenas I have restructured my code as follows:

```
final ref =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("publicaciones");
final pos = location.direccion?.geoPoint;
Stream<List<Publicacion>> stream;
if (pos != null) {
  final geo = Geoflutterfire();
  stream = geo
      .collection(collectionRef: ref)
      .within(
        center: geo.point(
          latitude: pos.latitude,
          longitude: pos.longitude,
        ),
        field: "direccion.geoHash",
        radius: radio,
      )
      .map<List<Publicacion>>(
        (snap) =>
            snap.map((s) => Publicacion.fromSnapshot(s)).toList(),
      );
} else {
  stream = ref.snapshots().map<List<Publicacion>>((snap) =>
      snap.docs.map((s) => Publicacion.fromSnapshot(s)).toList());
}
```

Then I used my stream:

```
return StreamBuilder<List<Publicacion>>(
  stream: stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map returns and iterable so we have to remember to add the "toList()" at the end.
With the `Stream<List<DocumentSnapshots>>` we could continue mapping the snapshots to a specific model class by the following:

```
stream.map((snapshot) {final data = snapshot.data(); 
return data != null ? Publicacion.fromSnapshot(data) 
: null
}).toList();
```

And then try your streambuilder with something like this:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Publicacion>>(
stream: stream, builder: (context, snapshot) {
if(snapshot.hasData) { final pubs = snapshot.data; 
  final children = pubs.map((pub) => 
 Text(pub.name)).toList(); 
  return ListView(children: children); 
} return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); 
 } if(snapshot.hasError){ return Center(child: 
  Text('Some error occurred')); 
 }return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
 )
```

In general do the data conversions before calling the streambuilder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it has helped me a lot.